# Handheld Linux device can't see one wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm using a Nokia N810 running OS 2008 (version 5.2008.43-7; should be the latest). It can see networks up and down the street in my neighborhood and can connect to mine using WEP. I can also connect to free networks at restaurants and the like.

When I bring it into work, it can't see a wireless network ("No connections available"). When I use netstumbler on my laptop I can see a list of several essids showing green connectivity for the network. I know that the network has its essid broadcast, and I know that it's unsecured.

When I run iwlist wlan0 scan, I see several APs with no essid, but I don't see anything with an essid set. I have verified using iwlist that my hardware supports the correct channels and speeds.

I know this isn't a Nokia/mobile forum, but it's running what's basically a Debian kernel. Any suggestions on what to do in this case? I'm really frustrated by this.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: whether it's an acceptable question has more to do with how you're trying to configure this; if you can access a commandline and tools i think it's ok, but if you're just using the standard Nokia GUI tools it's more of a phone question and i think you're better off on one of the smartphone q-and-a sites in this list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I have access to a linux command line and toolset, including root access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My premise was faulty.

> I know that the network has its essid broadcast

Not actually true, apparently. When I manually entered the ssid, it worked fine.

Dur!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for the N810, but it seems like the N800 has problems accessing [some Wifi channels](http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=4115).